# Creating events in a java class

Tags: java, events

In C# I can create events on a class such that I can wireup methods to execute when the event occurs like:

```
user.OnSave += someCallback;
user.OnDelete += otherCallback;
```

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I would use a Listener to do this.

Comment: @Kleric, how do you use Listeners?

Answer (score 2):

You do this by implementing either the observer pattern in java (Java.util.observer and observable) or creating your own events and event listeners outlined here: http://castever.wordpress.com/2008/07/31/how-to-create-your-own-events-in-java/

Edit: In that link it shows how java uses the event pattern, which consists of creating a subclass which inherits from java.awt.Event, and creating an interface which implements Java.util.Event listener you then add a function which implements the concrete interface. The final step is to add the event throwing eg. your save and adding the catching.

The full java tutorial is here:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html

Comment: Sorry I joined about a week ago, I have expanded my answer, I just don't have full sample code kicking around.

Answer (score 0):

An example implementation see at [Promise.java](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j/blob/master/df4j-core/src/com/github/rfqu/df4j/core/Promise.java). It uses some interfaces that lie in the same package.